# Parse folder names and rename folders by using a batch command

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm trying to rename a large number of folders that have dates as names.  I have created a test folder that contains just two such folders.  Their names are

1-23-2014
10-1-2016

I want to rename them to

2014-01-23
2016-10-01

In a command window run as administrator (probably not necessary) I have entered these commands.

```
C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Test Batch Job>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 30C3-D653

 Directory of C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Test Batch Job

12/11/2016  01:52 PM    <DIR>          .
12/11/2016  01:52 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/27/2016  10:33 PM    <DIR>          1-23-2014
11/27/2016  10:33 PM    <DIR>          10-1-2016
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  309,874,257,920 bytes free

C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Test Batch Job>for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%A in ("%~dp0") do rename %%A-%%B-%%C %%C-%%A-%%B
%%A was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Test Batch Job>
```

I'm aware that I don't deal with the missing leading zeros with this command -- I'll deal with that after I get this command working.

I am getting the error message

%%A was unexpected at this time.

How can I get past this error?  Thanks.

Comment: Wow, usually when somebody has this problem, it's the other way around. When you're running a for loop in the command prompt, you use `%A` instead of `%%A`.

Comment: Very odd trying to use `%~dp0` from the command line. That only has meaning from within a batch script, where your `%%A` would work fine.

Comment: You might want to check out my [regular expression batch/JScript renaming utility JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). With this, the full solution from within a batch script would be `call jren "^(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)-(\d{4})$" "$3+'-'+lpad($1,'00')+'-'+lpad($2,'00')" /d /j`, and it leaves directories alone that don't match your date template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output of the batch looks right, remove the `echo` in the last line.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Base=C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Test Batch Job
pushd %Base%
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/AD *-*-* ^|findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*-[0-9][0-9]*-[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"'
) Do call :Sub %%A %%B %%C
popd
goto :Eof
:Sub month day year
If %1 gtr 12 Goto :Eof
Set /A "yy=%3,mm=%1+100, dd=%2+100"
Echo Rename "%1-%2-%3" "%yy%-%mm:~-2%-%dd:~-2%"
```

- For /f parses the line passed from `Dir`and filtered by the findstr regex
- `tokens=1-3 Delims=-`means the line is split into 3 parts splitting at `-` assigning the for vars %%A - %%C
- In the sub these are received as arguments %1 - %3
- `Set /A` adds 100 to month and day
- `%mm:~-2%` takes only the last two places giving a leading zero if less than 10

Aschipls comments are right, the above changed version should work

Comment: You forgot the closing `"` at the `findstr` command line. Your `findstr` search string (reg expr.) is wrong, there is no special `+` token supported, so the `[0-9]+` part does *not* mean "one or more decimal digits", it simply means "one decimal digit, followed by a plus sign"; you could replace it by `[0-9][0-9]*`, which means "one decimal digit, followed by zero or more decimal digits", which in turn means what you intended to achieve by `[0-9]+`...

Comment: Alternatively, you could provide multiple search strings using the `/C` option, one of which must be matched, like: `findstr /C:"^[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" /C:"^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" /C:"^[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" /C:"^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"`

Comment: @aschipfl You are right. But a `[0-9][0-9]*` is easier. I know that but switching the script languages and RegEX versions in the last time got my on the wrong track. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I had to change RenDir to Rename, but then it worked perfectly.  Fantastic!